# When $d \in D$ irreducible implies $d+I \in \frac{D}{I}$ irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

Let $D$ be a commutative $k$-algebra which is a UFD, $k$ a field of characteristic zero.

Let $0 \neq a,b \in R$ be two irreducible elements of $D$, hence
$\frac{D}{\langle a \rangle}$ is an integral domain and 
$\frac{D}{\langle b \rangle}$ is an integral domain.
To exclude trivial cases, we also require that $\{a,b\}$ are linearly independent over $k$.

> When $\bar{a}:=a+\langle b \rangle \in \frac{D}{\langle b \rangle}$ is
>   irreducible?

**Example:** $D=k[x,y]$, $a=x$, $b=y$. Clearly, $\bar{x} \in \frac{k[x,y]}{\langle y \rangle}\cong k[x]$ is irreducible.

But I guess that generally, $\bar{a}$ may not necessarily be irreducible in $\frac{D}{\langle b \rangle}$.

**Remarks:**

**(1)** From our assumptions, it follows that $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Indeed, write
$a=da', b=db'$, where $D \ni d=\gcd(a,b)$. But $\{a,b\}$ are irreducibles in $D$,
hence $d \in k$ and we are done or $d \notin k$, hence $a',b' \in k$, so $\{a,b\}$ are linearly dependent over $k$, a contradiction to our assumption.

**(2)** If $\bar{a}$ is reducible, then there exist $u,v \in D-\langle b \rangle- k$ such that
$\bar{a}=\bar{u}\bar{v}$, so $a-uv \in \langle b \rangle$. Therefore, there exists $w \in D$ such that $a-uv=wb$. 
This shows that $uv \in \langle a,b \rangle$, but we have no information about $\frac{D}{\langle a,b \rangle}$.

**(3)** Edit: According to the first comment, we should also require that $k$ is algebraically closed.

**(4)** [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255193/is-there-a-characterisation-of-irreducibility-via-ideals-quotient-ring) question is relevant.
For $D=k[x,y]$, perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710686/regarding-irreducibility-of-two-variable-polynomial) question is relevant (but only if one of $\{a,b\}$ belongs to $k[x]$ or $k[y]$).

Any hint and comments are welcome!

Comment: Consider $a=y^2+1$ and $b=x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$. We have $\bar{a}=\overline{1+y^2}=(1+xy)(1-xy)$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(a)$.

Comment: @pigeon, thank you very much! What if $k=\mathbb{C}$? ($a$ and $b$ are reducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$).

Comment: (Of course, you meant in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]/(b)$).